# get drag object in GWT 2.4

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I heard that drag and drop feature has finally come to GWT 2.4, i know how to use it through this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEkR1ox_K10

However, that video only show using drag and drop to transfer string. I want to get the object that is being drag, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 2.4 frameworks is jet to come out, there probably isn't anyone who can give you a none theoretical answer!

If drag&drop for widgets isn't supported by GWT I would give an unique id to each dragabble object and then, on the drop event, use DOM manipulation to move the object to the new location.

Hope this helps

Comment: actually, i was already able to duplicate the video's example using a beta version of GWT 2.4 :D